# Connection closed before receiving a handshake response in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, angular6

I'm trying to do a socket connection. But i get the above error. I'm tryin to implement https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-websockets-tutorial/ with a different endpoint.

> **socket.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketService {

constructor() { }

private subject: Rx.Subject<MessageEvent>;

public connect(url): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
if (!this.subject) {
  this.subject = this.create(url);
  console.log("Successfully connected: " + url);
  } 
  return this.subject;
  }

  private create(url): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
  let ws = new WebSocket(url);

  let observable = Rx.Observable.create(
  (obs: Rx.Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
    ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
    ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
    ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);
    return ws.close.bind(ws);
   })
 let observer = {
    next: (data: Object) => {
        if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
            ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    }
}
return Rx.Subject.create(observer, observable);
}
}
```

> **chat.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {SocketService} from '../services/socket.service';

let ws_scheme = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
let ws_path = ws_scheme + '://' + window.location.host + 
"/api/chat/stream/";
const CHAT_URL = ws_path;

export interface Message {
author: string,
message: string
}

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UploadSocketService {

public messages: Subject<Message>;

constructor(wsService: SocketService) { 
this.messages = <Subject<Message>>wsService
        .connect(CHAT_URL)
        .map((response: MessageEvent): Message => {
            let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
            return {
                author: data.author,
                message: data.message
            }
        });
}
}
```

I get an error in **socket.service.ts** where the code is let ws = new WebSocket(url);

How to resolve this?

Comment: What version of Angular/RxJS are you using?  What does the error say?

Comment: Angular verson is 6. Rxjs version is 6.3.3. The error says  "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4200/api/chat/stream/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response". I do get a console message saying successfully connected from my socket.service.ts

Comment: I don't think you have to import * as RX in your socket server, but that also probably isn't your issue.  Sounds like there is a problem on your API side, not in your angular code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the angular cli proxy to get /api/ to go to your backend, you need to add the `ws: true` to the proxy config or else it won't be able to create the websocket connection.

```
{
  "/api/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
    "ws":true
  }
}
```